# 'Switch' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef and Importing 'switch' isn't helping either

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem** :

> 'Switch' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef.

I tried to import the switch module but it ain't working either. Switch import statement

```js
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Importing switch isn't working.

```js
import './App.css';
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Checkout />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i don't see Switch being imported

Comment: "import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';" this is the import statement. It's also throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

Use "Routes" instead of "Switch". This will solve the issue.

Comment: This is the right answer, but you should extend it with an explanation:
Switch was replaced by Routes in `react-router-dom` v6. You can read more about it here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

Answer (score 2):

The new version on react router dom package does not use 'Switch' but 'Routes'

```
import './App.css';
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Checkout />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try importing the switch this way  from react-router

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
```

or install react-router-dom properly

```
npm install --save react-router react-router-dom
```

this may solve the problem